# How to change directive data according to user actions

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Ive got a directive

```
angular.module('test', [])
.run(function($http, $templateCache) {
    $http.get('http://localhost/testtem/test.html', {
        cache: $templateCache
    });
})
.directive('ngTest', ['$parse', '$http', '$compile',    '$templateCache','$location',
    function ($parse, $http, $compile, $templateCache,$location)
{

    var linker = function (scope, element, attrs,ngModel)
    {
        element.bind('click', function () {

        var ddd = scope.selectedvalue;
            scope.testDataList = Enumerable.From(scope.testDataList)
            .Where(function (x) {
                return x.LeafParentId == '1' //leafParentId
            }).ToArray()


        });



    };
return {

    templateUrl : 'http://localhost/testtem/test.html',
    transclude: true,
    restrict: "E",
    scope: false,

    link: linker
};
 }]);
```

and this is the template :

```
<section ng-controller="testCtrl">
 <section class="box1">
<input type="button" name="" id="1"
       ng-value="checkData(DataList[0].Name)" 
 />             
</section>
<section class="box1">
<input type="button" name="" id="2"
       ng-value="checkData(DataList[1].Name)" 
 />              
</section>
<section class="box1">
    <input type="button" name="" id="3"
       ng-value="checkData(DataList[2].Name)" 
  />              
 </section>
```

this is the app + ctrl :

```
angular.module('templateApp', ['test'])
.controller('testCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $sce) {


    $scope.testDataList = "";

    $http.post("http://localhost/Service.svc/GetDataMysql",     {      leafParentId:      0 })
    .then(
        function (data) {
            if (data.data) {
                $scope.testData = Enumerable.From(data)
                            .Select(function (x) { return x })
                            .ToArray();
                $scope.testDataList = $scope.testData[0].Value;
            }
        });
```

this is the html:

```
 <section data-ng-app="templateApp">
        <div data-ng-controller="testCtrl">

             <ng-test ></ng-test>
            </div>


        </section>
```

just to be clear all functionality work perfect excepted the dom rendering.
I want to show the values according to the user actions
when i init again the testDatalist in the element.bind function ( on the directive)

i try to  use compile and watch and nothing happen,

Thanks,
Ishay

Comment: directive name doesn't match tag. Also, better not to use `ng-`prefix for custom directives ... implies it's part of angular. Create demo that replicates problem

Comment: thanks, i edit the names, just for the example , the names are correct, i want to know how to render the dom again according to user actions.

Comment: i understand that i need to use watch/compile, but where?

Comment: oh.. inside click event when change scope...angular doesn't know about it. Would be best to use `ng-click` instead of binding own click handler ... or use `scope.$apply()`